# SafeCracker validate if custom field is not a duplicate

Tags: safecracker

I have a safeCracker form that takes in users e-mail address. I would like to validate that a user that has already registered is not registering for a second time.

Anyway to accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

The Safecracker supports some of the CodeIgnitor's validation rules (http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/modules/safecracker/#rules-my-field-name) but it doesn't support the validation rule for "is_unique".

I 'm still wondering this rule is available in CodeIgnitor but not in EE which uses CodeIgnitor.

There may be 2 ways to achieve it.

1) You can add new rule for "is_unique" with form validation file "/system/codeigniter/system/libraries/Form_validation.php". But I am not sure it would work for EE as never tried it.

2) An extension can be developed using the hook "safecracker_submit_entry_start", in this extension, check for unique email address and throw the error if already registered.
I am sure about this approach and it will work.

I hope, it would help you.